# Checking if part of the elements of a list are repeated

Tags: python

I have a list that I am filling up in the following way:

```
complete = []
for (i,j) in list:
    complete.append('%s %s %s'%(i,j,R[i,j]))
```

The list has (as an example) the following elements:

```
complete = ['B A 1', 'A H 1', 'P B 1', 'H B 1', 'B W 1', 'B M 9', 'M R 9', 'R P 9', 'P A 9', 'C S 7', 'B C 7', 'B A 7', 'A H 7', 'B P 7', 'M B 7', 'P B 7', 'H B 7']
```

I want to check which letters are repeated, and on that case add the numbers corresponding to them.
On this example, (B A) is repeated with 1 and 7, so one of the outputs would have to be 'B A 8'.

I could also change the way I am appending the elements to complete, but I do not know how other way.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
from collections import Counter, defaultdict
complete =  ['ASO BAIS 1', 'HEL CIO 5'] 

d = Counter([i[:-1] for i in complete])

new_d = defaultdict(int)

for i in complete:
   if d[i[:-1]] > 0:
     new_d[i[:-1]] += int(i[-1])

print(dict(new_d))
#maximum value:
maximum = max(new_d.values())
print(maximum)
```

Output:

```
{'HEL CIO ': 5, 'ASO BAIS ': 1}
```

Comment: nice!! thanks. What if the list is not 'A B 1' 'H C 5'.... and instead is 'ASO BAIS 1' 'HEL CIO 5' ? Instead of the letters words of random size?

Comment: @IgnacioGarcia please see my recent edit. I merely changed the indices for the list slicing to create a more robust solution that will work for the input that you specified.

Comment: Thanks so much! And last of all, How could I now obtain the maximum value of this new_d? Something such as max(new_d) = 5.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done very simply in two steps:

1. First, get a list of the unique letter pairs in your list. This will be used to make a dictionary.
2. Next, iterate over each element in your list and use the current letter pair to index the dictionary. Increment that letter pair's key value pair in the dictionary by cast the last character in the element to a integer.

---

```
>>> lst = ['B A 1', 'A H 1', 'P B 1', 'H B 1', 'B W 1', 'B M 9', 'M R 9', 'R P 9', 'P A 9', 'C S 7', 'B C 7', 'B A 7', 'A H 7', 'B P 7', 'M B 7', 'P B 7', 'H B 7']
>>> keys = set(key[:3] for key in lst)
>>> 
>>> new_dict = {key: 0 for key in keys}
>>> for el in lst:
...     new_dict[el[:3]] += int(el[4])
... 
>>> new_dict
{'B C': 7, 'H B': 8, 'R P': 9, 'B A': 8, 'B P': 7, 'B M': 9, 'P A': 9, 'A H': 8, 'C S': 7, 'M B': 7, 'M R': 9, 'P B': 8, 'B W': 1}
>>>
```

Comment: Thanks @Christian Dean . How could I now obtain the maximum value of this new_dict ? Something such as max(new_dict) = 9.

Comment: @IgnacioGarcia You can get the max value of the dictionaries values: `max(new_dict.values())`.